# Are heroku servers slow?

Tags: node.js, heroku, digital-ocean, web-hosting

I have a node js webiste, when I run it on localhost on my computer, it runs blazingly fast but when I deploy it on heroku, it becomes very slow. So will this also happen if I host my site with digital ocean or any other hosting provider?

This is my package.json

```
  {
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon app"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cryptr": "^6.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.5",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "flatted": "^3.2.5",
    "got": "^12.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.1",
    "most-common-words-by-language": "^3.0.10",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.4",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "workbox-cli": "^6.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: ...how can we possibly answer this without any more information? Can you provide a [mre]? Are you running a production build? Are you even using technology that _has_ production builds? Please read [ask].

Comment: Like, what should I provide? The problem is not the code but the speed. Anyways, I provided my package.json. I don't know how my app.js will help you. If you need it pls tell me, I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely not a hosting provider issue but rather a [limitation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits) issue.

Heroku uses the Linux containers **Dynos** to execute your code in their platform, and they have multiple types with differentiating characteristics. If you have an unverified account, then you're given the `free` dyno type by default. Check Heroku's [dynos](https://www.heroku.com/dynos) page. You'll see that for the "*Always on*" row, the `free` type has the trait:

> "Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity, otherwise always on depending on your remaining monthly free dyno hours."

This is your issue. Your app starts slower when the dynos are asleep. The speed improves as you continue using the app, but it's not going to be performant and it's going to start slow again once the app is inactive for 30 mins. If you want your app to be *blazingly fast* in Heroku, then you need to [verify your account](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification) and purchase a non `free` or `hobby` dyno type.

Take note that you will also face similar issues with other hosting providers if you are using free account on their platform.